# Why is answers is different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, logic, eulers-number

I have answers of this code of finding Euler number:

```py
import math 

Sn = 0

x = 1

big_n = 10000

for i in range(0,big_n,1):
    Sn = Sn + ((x**i)/(math.factorial(i)))

print(Sn)
print(math.e)
```

##### Output:

```
2.7182818284590455
2.718281828459045
```

Why is first output is for one digit more than second one?

I think this is because math.e has constant length but teacher says it doesn't

Comment: It's rounding errors.  The result of your division cannot be expressed exactly in binary, so you get a very close approximation.  As you add more and more close approximations, the errors accumulate.  A floating point number only holds 15 or 16 decimal digits, and your two values are exactly equal to 16 places.  Anything after that is garbage.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think these *would* / *should* be the same? The "true" value of e is 2.7182818284590452... and defined by an infinite number of terms, so your `Sn` clearly is an approximation and the added digit isn't actually precise.